# StructureMap - Initialise Entity Framework for each database on a multitenant web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, structuremap, multi-tenant

We are developing a multi tenanted ASP.NET MVC web application. Each tenant has their own database. Data access is managed by the entity framework. StructureMap is being used as the IoC container. The entity framework data context has been setup with http request scope. For each request the tenant is worked out and StructureMap returns a new instance of the entity framework data context and repository classes.

In the start up class of the web app (implementation of IProcessHostPreloadClient) I would like to initialise the entity framework - I would need to loop around and create a new instance of the datacontext for each configured tenant. What is the best way of going about this? StructureMap would return the same data context as it has been setup to cache with http/thread scope.

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to vary the connection string based on the tenant, the following should work:

```
For<Tenant>().Use(c => c.GetInstance<TenantFactory>().CreateTenant());
For<DbContext>().Use(c => new DbContext(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[c.GetInstance<Tenant>().ConnectionName]
        .ConnectionString));
```

The `Tenant` class should hold the current tenant connection string name and the `TenantFactory` would create the appropriate `Tenant` unsing whatever method you use for determining the connection string.

If it's a more extensive variation, a [multi-container approach](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/?tag=/multi-tenancy) might be better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have got the correct connection string being picked using a similar method. During the IIS web start I want to create the context for every single tenant. As StructureMap is configured to cache the context objects per request/thread, it will return the same object on each call. What is the recommended approach to get StructureMap to return a new instance per tenant on startup only?

Comment: You shouldn't cache the context per tenant. You'd want to cache it per  HttpRequest. If you cache it per tenant and reuse the same context between requests you're going to run into concurrency problems. Stick with using HttpContextScoped on the DbContext registration.

Comment: The context is being cached per http request - a new one will be created for each request. However, I also want to create the context objects at the beginning to get the Entity Framework initialised and thus avoid this cost occurring on the first request. I am talking about building the entity model up in memory and the check done by the entity framework to check that the database structure matches the model.